# Is it possible to open native facebook app login dialog from web app on android?

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, cordova, mobile-website

I have a mobile web app that uses facebook api for login. We use facebook javascript api and it works fine, but it opens up the login dialog in a browser window.

I would just like to know if it is possible make use of the native facebook app (from the mobile web-app) if it is installed on the user's device.

One possibility would be to use phonegap wrapper and then implement the procedure there, but I was wondering if there is a simpler solution.

Comment: do you create android project or not

Comment: Yes, I have created an android project.

Comment: any solution you got so far?